# For loop stop working properly after XY number of loops

Tags: excel, vba, for-loop, runtime-error, paste

i have this kind of problem:

Everything runs smoothly in my VBA macro, until i = 3224. It means for example, if i=3000 then code works well, but if **i** = 3224 it stop working corrently. Error message is **Run-time error '1004': Fill down method of range class failed** I click on debug and try to move on manually (F8) and it works. But in next **i** this happened again and again. I tried to change code to Selection.Copy but Paste has same kind of error, so it looks like I am not able to Paste values if i>=3224 (it should run to at least 5227). Anyone have some solutions for this problem? Core data has about 1200 rows, if i run macro on 600 rows, it works well, but if I duplicate that 600 rows and make 1200 rows, it has this error (so problem isn't in core data).

This is only part of the code, in this part i want to fill every blank row with previous nonblank row until last row in worksheet.

```
Dim LastRow As Long
Dim i As Long
LastRow = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count
For i = 3 To LastRow
Range("A" & i).Select
If IsEmpty(ActiveCell) = False Then
    i = i
Else: Rows(i & ":" & i).Select
    Selection.FillDown
EndIf
Next
```

Comment: What do you expect from `Rows(i & ":" & i).FillDown`?

Comment: it is best to be specific on what you are actually trying to do

Comment: Rows(i & ":" & i).FillDown - i want to copy and paste previous row into next blank row.

Comment: What do you mean by "previous row"? `i - 1` row? And which to be the "next blank row", wherever will it be? The really next blank row? The `i` row? Did you see the Microsoft definition for `FillDown` method (see [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.filldown))?

Comment: In other words, do you want copying the content of the above row of an empty cell in A:A column?

Comment: I don't understand your code, but modifying the loop variable inside the loop is never a good sign...

Comment: yes, variable 'i' stand for row rank, this for_loop is searching for empty rows (if "A" & i is empty then whole row is empty), and if it finds empty row, it should copy previous row 'i-1' and paste it to current row 'i'. It works until 'i=3224', it doesnt make any sense to me why it stop working after 3224 rows.

Answer (score 3):

### Fill Rows

[image]

```vb
Sub FillRows()
    
    Const HEADER_ROWS As Long = 2
    Const CRITERIA_COLUMN As Long = 1
    
    Dim rg As Range, rCount As Long, cCount As Long
    
    With ActiveSheet ' improve!
        With .UsedRange
            rCount = .Rows.Count - HEADER_ROWS
            cCount = .Columns.Count
            Set rg = .Resize(rCount).Offset(HEADER_ROWS)
        End With
    End With
    
    Dim Data(): Data = rg.Value
    Dim cr As Long: cr = 1
    
    Dim r As Long, c As Long, rStr As String
    
    For r = 2 To rCount
        rStr = CStr(Data(r, CRITERIA_COLUMN))
        If Len(rStr) = 0 Then
            For c = 1 To cCount
                Data(r, c) = Data(cr, c)
            Next c
        Else
            cr = r
        End If
    Next r
        
    rg.Value = Data
        
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you for your help, but i am afraid that my VBA skills aren't as good. Maybe if nothing else helps i will try to replicate your code.

Answer (score 1):

I didn't find any reason why there was error message, but i change code a little bit, and now it works.

```
Dim a As Variant

LastRow = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count

For i = 3 To LastRow

Range("A" & i).Select

If IsEmpty(ActiveCell) = False Then
    i = i
Else: With Sheets("testovacie data (3)")
     a = .Rows(i - 1 & ":" & i - 1)
     .Rows(i & ":" & i) = a
    End With
End If

Next
```

Answer (score 0):

Try change

```
Else: Rows(i & ":" & i).Select
```

to this

```
Else
Range(Rows(i-1),Rows(i)).Select
```

Comment: I tried it, it displays same error on same i=3224.